# initialize logger in class to use in retry decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, decorator

Iam writing a database client and i want use a specific logger in the retry decorator:

```py
import pandas as pd
from retry import retry
from set_up.SetUp import set_logging, set_up_environment, get_retry_parameters


class DBClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = set_logging()
        self.connection = set_up_environment()
        self.tries,self.delay = get_retry_parameters()

    @retry(tries=tries, delay=delay, logger=log)
    def get_artist_table(self):
```

Is there a possibility to use the variables that i instantiate the class with in the retry decorator (it's an external library).

Answer (score 2):

Using retry_call instead of retry. This should be sufficient for your requirement.  https://github.com/invl/retry/blob/master/retry/api.py#L79

```
import pandas as pd
from set_up.SetUp import set_logging, set_up_environment, get_retry_parameters
from retry.api import retry_call

def retrydecorator(func):
    def inner(self, *fargs, **fkwargs):
        result = retry_call(func, fargs=(self,)+fargs, fkwargs=fkwargs, tries=self.tries, delay=self.delay, logger=self.log)
        return result
    return inner

class DBClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = set_logging()
        self.connection = set_up_environment()
        self.tries,self.delay = get_retry_parameters()

    @retrydecorator
    def get_artist_table(self):
        pass
```

Comment: thank you very much, this works like a charm, i just could not wrap my head around it but you saved me!

Comment: Thanks for this, it is working well and retrying as expected, however not generating any log. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure your logger supports and log Level is warning.  
  :param logger: logger.warning(fmt, error, delay) will be called on failed attempts.
                   default: retry.logging_logger. if None, logging is disabled.

https://github.com/invl/retry/blob/master/retry/api.py#L40